# Como sacar diferencia entre Dos fechas usando DateTime::createFromFormat y date_diff en formato AM/PM PHP?

Tags: php

chicos necesito sacar la diferencia de una fecha a otra. por ejemplo, que diferencia hay en días, meses, años, horas, minutos o segundos.
Este es mi código php.

```
<?php
$fecha_actual = date("04/03/2020 05:30:00 AM");
$fecha_entrada = date("19/02/2000 05:45:00 AM");

$fecha1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s A', $fecha_actual);
$fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s A', $fecha_entrada);
$fechaF = date_diff($fecha1, $fecha2);

echo $fechaF;
?>
```

Pero este es el mensaje o resultado:

> Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given in C:\xampp.... on line ...

no sé como podría hacerlo, también recalco que el formato debe ser `(d/m/Y h:i:s A)` ya que uno de los datos viene desde la bd, agradezco sus ayudas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen 3 problemas en tu código.

1. [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) toma como primer parámetros **el formato** en que va a devolver la fecha.
2. [`date_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php) falla porque `$fecha_actual` y `$fecha_entrada` son `false` ya que `date()` no reconoce el *"formato indicado"*
3. [`date_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php) devuelve un [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php) el cual no se puede imprimir.

### Solución:

Podrías usar [`DateTime->diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php) y [`DateInterval->format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.format.php) así:

```
<?php
$fecha_actual = "04/03/2020 05:30:00 AM";
$fecha_entrada = "19/02/2000 05:45:00 AM";

$fecha1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s A', $fecha_actual);
$fecha2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s A', $fecha_entrada);
$interval = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);

echo $interval->format('%R%Y años, %M meses, %D días, %H horas, %I minutos, %S segundos');
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50dcb53dbb43a5c38709ac43bff08f4f9915c9d1)</kbd>

Comment: cómo puedo imprimir el resultado incluyendo AM Ó PM? ej: 04/03/2020 05:30:00 AM

Comment: Eso no tiene sentido, `AM` y `PM` sirven para deferenciar por ejemplo cuando hablamos `06:00:00 PM`, que en realidad son las `18:00:00`. **Lo que estamos calculando es el tiempo transcurrido entre dos fechas y no una fecha/momento en el tiempo**.

Comment: sí, sé que no tiene mucho sentido, pero se puede hacer?

Comment: inpenpendientemente del resultado puedo convertir ese resultado de h:m:s a una hora AM/PM, usando esa misma función? si por ejemplo el resultado  es 00:00:00 entonces quiero pasarlo a 12:00:00 AM o tendria que hacer una función propia, gracias.

Comment: Si, lo podes hacer, pero imprimirlo en ese formato me da la sensación que se prestaría a confución, por lo que te comento. Lo que tendrías que hacer es obtener las horas (`$horas = $interval->format('%H');`) y si es mayor a `12` entonces tendrías que agregar `PM` y restarle `12` (`$horas -= 12; $meridiano = 'PM';`)

Comment: ok, gracias por la ayuda, me sirvio mucho.